# What is the ENU keyboard setting?

Tags: keyboard, language-setting

I use two languages on the phone, Swedish (SVE) and English (ENG). But when I change the language when typing, I also see a language code ENU. What is it?

[image: ENU keyboard language]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

enu stands for **En** glish **U** nited States.

in the keyboard settings you can select your languages. go to:

**Settings -> Keyboard -> choose keyboard languages**

you can deselect either English United States (ENU) or English United Kingdom (ENG)

Comment: Thanx! I couldn't find it. ENU is United states, and ENG is UK on my phone though...

Comment: oops yeah i mixed it up. tnx for fixing my answer

Comment: You're welcome :-)