# How do I use a different keyboard language?

Tags: keyboard, language-setting

Is there a way to temporarily switch the language (or really just the keyboard) for my phone to Japanese? I'm learning Japanese and wanted to practice on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On WindowsPhone.com, there is a pretty good [tutorial](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/change-keyboard-language) on this.

```
1. On Start, flick left to the App list, then tap Settings > Keyboard.

2. Select all the languages you'd like to be able to use from your keyboard. 
   The next time you use your keyboard, you'll see a button next to the Space bar 
   that indicates which language you're currently using on your keyboard.

3. Tap the button to switch between all the languages you've selected. For example,
   if you usually use a US English keyboard, tap the ENU button, and the keyboard
   switches to the next language you've selected.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the [answer here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/420/what-is-the-enu-keyboard-setting)

Go to **Settings -> Keyboard**
There is an option to download additional keyboards including Japanese 12 Key and QWERTY

Comment: Is it possible to you mask you own answer as "the answer" of the question? If you can, please do this. ;)

Comment: It said I had to wait two days before I could do so :)